# Django Celery FIFO

Tags: django, redis, celery, fifo

So I have this 2 applications connected with a REST API (json messages). One written in Django and the other in Php. I have an exact database replica on both sides (using mysql).

When i press "submit" on one of them, i want that data to be saved on the current app database, and start a cron job with celery/redis to update the remote database for the other app using rest.

***My question is, how do i attribute the same worker to my tasks in order to keep a FIFO order?***

I need my data to be consistent and FIFO is really important.

Ok i am going to detail what i want to do a little further:

So i have this django app, and when i press submit after i fill in the form my celery worker wakes up and takes care of taking that submitted data and posting to a remote server. This i can do without problems.

Now, imagine that my internet goes down at that exact time, my celery worker keeps retrying to send until it is successful  But imagine i do another submit before my previous data is submitted, my data wont be consistent on the other remote server.

Now that is my problem. I am not able to make this requests FIFO with the retry option given by celery so i that's were i need some help figuring that out.

Comment: Can't they just share database/use mysql replication?

Comment: You an achieve FIFO-style execution by using only one worker process.

Comment: how do i force it to use only 1 worker process?

Comment: no, i must do the replication over REST not sharing databases direclty

Comment: "must replicate over rest" sounds like sunk cost fallacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer i got from another forum:

Use named queues with celery: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues

Start a worker process with a single worker: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process

Set this worker to consume from the appropriate queue: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues-adding-consumers

For the fifo part i can sort my celery broker in a fifo order before sending my requests